# Spidermonkey : Send arguments from javascript to C++

Tags: javascript, android, c++, ios, spidermonkey

I am using Spidermonkey for Pacfile Parsing in iOS.I register a function with below code.

```
if (!JS_DefineFunction(cx, globalHandle, "dnsResolve", (JSNative) dns_resolve, 1, 1)) {
    print_error("%s %s\n", error_prefix,
                "Could not define dnsResolve in JS context.");

    return 0;   }
```

But when I call `dnsResolve` method with an argument I got garbage values.I use below code to parse arguments

```
static bool dns_resolve(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, jsval *argv)
{
    JS::CallArgs args = CallArgsFromVp(argc, argv);
    JSString *temp = JS::ToString(cx, args[0]);

    char* name = JS_EncodeString(cx, temp);
    JS_ConvertArgumentsVA(cx, args, name, NULL);
    return true;
}
```

While same code works on other platforms like Android,MAC,windows while gives garbage values in iOS.

Comment: Let's start with adding return statement to `dns_resolve` to remove UB

Comment: @bartop can you please let me know what does UB mean?

Comment: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#cite_note-C99_6.9.1/12-14)

Comment: I actually pasted argument parsing code only.My code does contain return statement.Let me put complete code here.